# Should ($_POST[""]) Return a Value if Queried with echo

Tags: php, html, forms

I've created a form which I'd like to upon the submit button being clicked, display an error if the text box is empty.  That much I've managed to get working.  My issue starts when I **do** fill out the text box and click submit.  Basically, nothing is returned.

I appreciate that the code below is probably atrocious but I'm still learning and haven't yet got around to formatting of code.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["node"])) {
            $nodeErr = "Hostname is required";
    } else {
            echo $node;
 }
}
```

My understanding is (albeit limited at this point) *echo $node* should return a value if captured with *($_POST["node"])* i.e. if the text field is complete but I think I'm missing a trick here.

Comment: You are wrong. However, `echo $_POST['node'];` will do that

Comment: What you refer to @Dan is an abomination and should never be used. I will not even name it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is right in the place you just checked.

```
if (empty($_POST["node"])) {
        $nodeErr = "Hostname is required";
} else {
        echo $_POST["node"];
}
```